# Autofilter a protected excel sheet opened from access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Im currently moving some code from excel to access. In excel there is a button that opens another excel document and applies an autofilter.

```
Dim cell As Long
cell = Sheet2.Cells(9, "i").Value    
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "C:/worksheet1.xls"
      Selection.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=cell
```

This is the code from excel and it used to work fine but now also throws an error because the sheet is protected.

Using some code I got from this thread [Autofilter Excel with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21730446/autofilter-excel-with-vba)

I came up with code that should work in access but doesn't

What I have so far is

```
Dim oApp As Object
Dim wb As Object
Dim ws As Object

Set oApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oApp.Visible = True

'tries to open workbook
On Error Resume Next
'change file path to the correct one
Set wb = oApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:="C:/worksheet1.xls")
On Error GoTo 0

'if workbook succesfully opened, continue code
If Not wb Is Nothing Then
    'specify worksheet name
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("BOM")
    With ws
        'apply new filter
        .Cells(3, 3).Select
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=110, Operator:=7
    End With
End If

Set wb = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing
```

Im getting an error on the .AutoFilter Field:=3, Critera1:=110, Operator:=7
I cant just select a range to autofilter because the sheet is protected and I do not have write access. There is already autofilters in place on the sheet I just need to set the value of one.

Does anybody know a solution to this in either access or excel but preferably both?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe an AutoFilter needs to be applied to a Range.  Your "With" statement resolves to a worksheet, not a range.

```
ws.Range(xxxxxx).Autofilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=110, Operator:=7
```

Unless someone that has access to the worksheet changes the protection using information from the following link, this cannot be done.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/enable-autofilter-functionality-for-a-protected-worksheet-HA001098270.aspx

I hope this helps.

Comment: You are correct but unfortunately that cannot be applied to a protected worksheet. Since I don't have write access I cant change it to unprotected.

Comment: I've added a Microsoft link that explains exactly what you are up against.  Please revisit my modified answer.  It's not what you want to hear, but it is an answer.

Comment: Appreciate the help! At least I know now